# Control table's width when displayed side by side

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Is there a way to control each table's width separately when displayed side-by-side like in the example below?

````
```{r sample, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
t1 <- head(mtcars)[1:3]
t2 <- head(mtcars)[4:6]
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
kable(t1) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "float_left")
kable(t2) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "left")
```
````

For example, I would like the first table below to have 2 times the width of the second table.

I tried `kable(format = 'html', table.attr = "style='width:80%;'")` but it doens't work and I don't know why. The width doesn't change at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried `kable(format = 'html', table.attr = "style='width:80%;'")` but
> it doens't work and I don't know why. The width doesn't change at all.

You were very close, just specify `full_width` to `TRUE`:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
kable(t1, format = "html", table.attr = "style = 'width: 69%;'") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = TRUE, position = "float_left")
kable(t2) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "left")
```
````

Output:
[image]

Comment: Very nice! Didn't knew that I had to set full_width... When I think about it now, it makes total sense.